# SET value for a particular node in XML

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

Hi I have an XML file like

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
 <PropertyGroup>
   <ExternalLibPath>XYZ</ExternalLibPath>
   <PropertyModelSDKPath>ABC</PropertyModelSDKPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="xyz" == 'true'">
   <DiagnosticConditionalDefines>FeatureA</DiagnosticConditionalDefines>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to set value in  to FeatureB using powershell.

I could do something like this to get the value

```
$xmlFile = [XML] (get-Content filename)
$xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup.DiagnosticConditionalDefines
```

But to write it I need to do something like

```
$xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup[2].DiagnosticConditionalDefines="FeatureB"
```

I'm not happy to give index value "2" here to write to this node as it might not stay that way.

How do I edit the value without adding index here

Comment: This is not valid xml...

Comment: @arco444 Try with <PropertyGroup Condition="'xyz' == 'true'">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I had to do it

```
$xmlFile = [xml] (Get-Content $file)
$value=[string] $xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup.DiagnosticConditionalDefines
for( $i=0; $i -lt $xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup.Count ; $i++)
     {
        if($xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup[$i].DiagnosticConditionalDefines.Length -gt 0)
        {
            $xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup[$i].DiagnosticConditionalDefines
            $xmlFile.Project.PropertyGroup[$i].DiagnosticConditionalDefines += "TEST"
        }
     }
    $xmlFile.Save($file.FullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and its working for me. Code may not be an optimized one, I am beginner in powershell

```
$xml = [xml](get-content "C:\temp.xml")
foreach($item in  $xml.Project.PropertyGroup)
{
    if($item.Condition -eq "'xyz' == 'true'")
    {
        $item.DiagnosticConditionalDefines = "FeatureDB"
    } 
}
$xml.Save($ProvisionFilePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the noted correction to your XML, this is one among several PowerShell-y ways to modify an element based on an attribute:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $fileName)
$node = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup |
   Where { $_.GetAttribute('Condition') -eq "'xyz' == 'true'"} 
$node.DiagnosticConditionalDefines = 'new value'
```

You can confirm that it has modified the original XML structure by just executing the selection again, this time without assigning it to a variable:

```
$xml.Project.PropertyGroup | ? { $_.GetAttribute('Condition') -eq "'xyz' == 'true'"}
```

A second way to verify is to write the updated contents back to the file and then examine the file:

```
$xml.Save($fileName)
```